# Explain this javascript function from Eloquent Javascript

Tags: javascript

I am having a hard time following this function. I do not understand how the variable `start` reverts back to 16 after it reaches a value of 26 which is greater than 24.

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal)
      return history;
    else if (start > goal)
      return null;
    else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

print(findSequence(24));
```

OK, after looking at this for sometime, I have a few questions that might clarify a few things:

1)  Is it a correct statement to say that each call to find keeps track of it's own start value?  For example, when find(1) is called, it's has a start value of 1, when find(1 + 5) is called, find(1)'s start value is still one, but find(1 + 5) now has it's own start value of 6.

2)  I am having a hard time following the stacktrace even if I see it printed out.  This is how I am viewing it:

find(1) calls find(1 + 5)     //start = 1

find(6) calls find(6 + 5)    // start = 6, Passes

find(11) calls find(11 + 5) // start = 11, Passes

find(16) calls find(16 + 5) // start = 16, Passes

find(21) calls find(21 + 5) // start = 21, Fails

Because find(21 + 5) returns null, it tries to call find(21 * 3) which also returns null.

This is the part I get stuck at, if both find(21 + 5) and find(21 * 3) return null, how does it know to call find(16 * 3) next.  Why does it not do find(16 + 5) again?

Does it have something to do where find(21 + 5) and find(21 * 3) were called by find(16) and because those returned null into the calling function, it executed the second portion of the || statement which was find(16 * 3).

Comment: don't two pipes mean "or"? how can you return one thing OR another?

Comment: @ScottC: in Javascript, "OR" `||` returns the first item if it is true-ish, or the second item if the first item is false-ish (which includes null). It's a generalization of the boolean-or, and behaves similarly to a null-coalesce operator.

Comment: @ScottC: Read the chapter in your Javascript book about boolean conditions. It's the same as `var x = y || z; return x;`.

Comment: @ Jimmy ah very cool...but true-ish and false-ish are kind of confusing ideas lol

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal I don't buy the textbooks lol, but I will be sure to google it! although I am sure I understand what you are saying now

Comment: @ScottC: You should get a book. You cannot learn programming by Googling.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Javascript..totally lost in this tutorial](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074862/javascript-totally-lost-in-this-tutorial)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal oh I have lots of textbooks but I think that there are a LOT of useful tutorials online that are dynamic and copy/pasteable which makes for much quicker testing(not plagiarism, just running a quick example to see how it works) ya know?

Comment: @ScottC: Sure, but be wary of many of them being incorrect/incomplete/misleading. :)

Comment: @Tomalak Geret'kal oh for sure, that's why I come here!(I upvoted your comment (be wary) above btw)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a different variable. start whenever a particular find(x) is called, its value of start doesn't affect any other instance of start.

when find(21) is called, it returns null, because find(26) and find(63) return null
likewise,
find(16) and find(11) return null

when find(6) is called, it calls find(11), which returns null, so it calls find(24) next. 
in the context of this call, start == 6, so it continues with start + 5 and start * 3.

```
find(6):
start = 6, history = (1 + 5)
     find(6 + 5):
     start = 11, history = ((1 + 5) + 5)
         find(11 + 5):
         start = 16, history = (((1 + 5) + 5) + 5)
         ... continued etc...

         find(11 * 3):
         start = 33, history = (((1 + 5) + 5) * 3)
         <end>
     find(6 * 3):
     start = 24, history = ((1 + 5) * 3)
```

Comment: I agree, the new instances of find contain new instances of start and history, maybe instead of passing the variable ByVal javascript has a way of passing ByRef?? like c++?

if that is infact what you are trying to accomplish

Comment: well, the stated function is correct. Xaisoft just seems to think there is a single context of find (there are multiple). Compare with "there is a single context of findSequence, and thus a single value for goal" (which is true)

Answer (score 6):

Perhaps you're not entirely convinced, but you got it.

Regarding question 1, it's correct to say that the `start` values are preserved along inner calls. It's like each call has its own "context" -- even if you modify the variables and argument values, this is not carried to the outer function call. That's scope.

Question 2 seems to be related to short-circuit boolean evaluation. The behavior is exactly what you described: once the expression at left of the `||` operator returns something "truey", the expression at right won't be evaluated. And the contrary is true as well: if the left expression is "falsey", then the interpreter will proceed to evaluate the right expression. The resulting value will be the first non-falsey value, or the last value in the chain.

So I think you got everything covered!

---

I altered the original script so it prints a call trace. See it in action [here](http://jsfiddle.net/nscDU/).

This is a partial trace where the value of `start` appears to "decrease" to 16 after it goes further:

[image]

The function goes a little further under the 16 branch, then it desists, reverting back to the upper call where `start` is 11. Then it proceeds to try a value of 11 * 3 for `start`, then it desists again, and so on.

Comment: Awesome, I am walking through it by hand and will probably update my question because I think I am getting it, but not quite yet.

Answer (score 2):

You're not considering that the recursion branches out. It may appear that start jitters up and down, but you're just reaching the bottom of one recursion tree and skipping to a different one.

Working through the calls:

---

Values of `start` in recursion tree (branching on `start+5`/`start*3`):

```
                        1
              6---------+----------3
        11----+--18          8-----+-----
     16-+-33  23-+--48    13-+--24
  21-+-80   28+69       18+39 
26+63                23+90
                    28+69
```

See how each branch ends when the value goes too high, then the value of `start` that you see goes down as processing jumps to the next branch rightwards. Processing stops when the '24' is found.

---

(Disclaimer: I haven't fully checked all the maths, but the principle should be sound!)

Comment: it's a depth-first search stopping when start > goal, so find(26) does happen before find(24) occurs, which is what Xaisoft is confused about.

Comment: @Jimmy: It doesn't stop when `start > goal`, it stops when `start == goal`. When `start > goal` the current tree is abandoned, but others are still searched.

Comment: yes, the confusion in the question is because he thinks there's only one value of start.

Comment: @Jimmy: Yep, and I have demonstrated how the value he's seeing -- presumably in a "watch" window -- can safely change up and down up and down, as the stack tree is swept.

Comment: oh, good call about the "watch" window. Sometimes I wonder how people make this misunderstanding.