# Eloquent Javascript's findSequence clarification

Tags: javascript, recursion

I am stuck on the following function which appears in a few other posts I've also reviewed.

```
function findSequence(goal) {
  function find(start, history) {
    if (start == goal)
      return history;
    else if (start > goal)
      return null;
   else
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)") ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)");
 }
  return find(1, "1");
}

print(findSequence(24));
```

Also given in this link.

[Javascript..totally lost in this tutorial](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5074862/javascript-totally-lost-in-this-tutorial)

In the above explanation, the answer instead tried to set a goal of 11. They have a start of 1, which is first tested against 11, and then a start of 6 which is tested against 11.

I understand these first two steps. However, I do not understand the leap from the 2nd step (comparing `start`:6 to `goal`:11) to the third step (comparing `start`:3 to `goal`:11).

How does `start` go from 6, back down to 3, and then back up to 11 (fourth bullet)?

Comment: English is my first language.

Comment: This explanation in the post is very useful, which is why I provided the link instead.

Comment: check this answer - maybe it can clarify. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7540111/javascript-closure-tutorial-from-eloquent-javascript?lq=1

Comment: c69, can you try to explain my question. I've also reviewed that post.

Comment: I'm really just trying to understand if +5 and *3 are returned together each time, or if +5 keeps going until it returns null, and then *3 is returned for the first time. There seems to be some conflicting explanations given here.

Comment: the *3 is only evaluated if the left-hand side of || evaluates to false. For example type `"" || "aaa"` in your JS console and then type  `"bbb" || "ccc"`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Ok, here is a version of the code which was enhanced with console log statements. Open Chrome/Opera/Firefox eveloper tools and execute this code there:

```
function findSequence (goal) {
  function find (start, history, depth) {
    depth = depth || 0;
    console.log( Array( ++depth ).join('--> '), start, goal, history );
    if (start == goal) {
      console.warn( 'history' );
      return history;
    } else if (start > goal) {
      console.error( 'null' );
      return null;
    } else {
      console.info('recursion!');
      return find(start + 5, "(" + history + " + 5)", depth) ||
             find(start * 3, "(" + history + " * 3)", depth);
    }
  }
  return find(1, "1");
}

console.info( findSequence(24) );
```

You will get a call trace of this program, and hopefully will grasp the concept of recursion visually, by looking on the trace.

Comment: I agree this will help him understand concept but by his comments I'd say his confusion lies in the `||`.

Comment: That is exactly what I needed to see and answers my question perfectly. Thank you very much.

Comment: pedrofurla, so, since the left side eventually returns null, it's is false, and triggers the right side to begin. Correct?